# Downloading images in scrapy

Tags: image, download, scrapy, imagedownload

I am trying to download image in via scrapy. Here are my different files :

items.py

```
class DmozItem(Item):
        title = Field()
        image_urls = Field()
        images = Field()
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline']
IMAGES= '/home/mayank/Desktop/sc/tutorial/tutorial'
```

spider

```
class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "wikipedia"
    allowed_domains = ["wikipedia.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pune"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        images=hxs.select('//a[@class="image"]')
        for image in images:
                item = DmozItem()
                link=image.select('@href').extract()[0]
                link = 'http://en.wikipedia.com'+link
                item['image_urls']=link
                items.append(item)
```

In spite of all these setting I my pipeline is not getting activated.Please help. I am new to this framework.

Comment: Have you installed PIL (Python Imaging Library)? It's a prerequisite for image downloads: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html

Comment: How do you know the pipeline is not being activated? Can you include a bit of the log output, something like: `2013-04-16 16:40:31-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: ImagesPipeline`.

Answer (score 10):

First, `settings.py`: IMAGES -> IMAGES_STORE

Second, `spider`: You should return an `item` so that `ImagesPipeline` could download those images.

```
item = DmozItem()
image_urls = hxs.select('//img/@src').extract()
item['image_urls'] = ["http:" + x for x in image_urls]
return item
```